# Laravel Eloquent return big array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is a function on my model:

```
static function getHashes()
{
    return self::select('hash')->get()->toArray();
}
```

How can I make laravel return one big array instead of an array with sub arrays?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague and usually you should at least post some of your code. However I think I might know what you want and I'm in a good mood so here goes...

If you want an array listing a value of a certain attribute of every model in your *collection* you can use `lists()`:

```
$hashes = $collection->lists('hash');
```

---

For your function that would be:

```
static function getHashes()
{
    return self::lists('hash');
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the mis-information, anyway I have a model and I want to select just one column and return it as one big array, this is the scope: http://pastebin.com/LWVUaR4v

Comment: Please note in Laravel 5.4+ lists() has been depreciated and now pluck() is used instead.